# Migration from Windows server 2003 to 2012 R2

Tags: group-policy, migration, sysvol

We went from Windows 2003 R2 to Windows Server 2012 R2. I did the following:

- Joined 2012 server to the 2003 domain
- Installed Active Directory Domain Services (aka `dcpromo`) on the server
- Transferred all roles to new server within `fsmo` maintenance under `ntdsutil`
- I don't remove the old Windows Server 2003 server

Everything seemed to be working OK (User synchronized to the new DC2012R2) until I saw errors with group policy not applying due to missing group policy folders - on closer inspection I had no SYSVOL or NETLOGON folders!

What can i do for resolve this problem?

Comment: Your migration failed.
Now you have to check : Who hold roles , your time setup(ntp) , your dns setup and a bit of google for other questions about dcdiag.exe the domain diag tool.

Answer (score 1):

It's a common issue with such migration as 2003R2 default replication is used FRS, while newer OS like 2008R2+ is defaulting to DFRS for the replication of that volume.

Please recreate the folder C:\Windows\SYSVOL\domain in the 20012R2 manually and restart the net-logon service.

If the replication is not working, please use the [D4-D2 BurFlags restoration's method](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/290762/using-the-burflags-registry-key-to-reinitialize-file-replication-servi) after the folder creation